# Smart Members Pro checkbox field not parsing in view profile tag

Tags: ee5

I recently purchased Smart Members Pro because I needed the checkbox functionality in custom member fields, among other features. I have the edit and view profile working just fine except where it relates to displaying data from a checkbox field. Radio buttons and all other custom member fields work fine but not checkboxes or multi-select.

This makes me think I have syntax wrong but the documentation mentions no special syntax for these fields. My question is does anyone else use this module and, if so, can you please help me with syntax to display a checkbox field in a member profile?

Here's an example. In this tag the field {allergy_checkbox} doesn't parse and simply renders as text. All other custom member fields in the profile parse just fine.

```
{exp:smart_members:profile
member_id = "" 
}

{allergy_checkbox}

{/exp:smart_members:profile}
```

Comment: what does the allergy_checkbox output? the value of the allergy? then it's easy to construct a checkbox field manually
<input type="checkbox" name="allergy_checkbox" id="allergy_checkbox" value="{allergy_checkbox}" {if allergy_checkbox} checked{/if}>

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of anyone with the same question I have the correct code for displaying a checkbox or multi-select field. This information is not in the documentation as of Oct. 2019

```
{exp:smart_members:profile
member_id = "" 
}

{allergy_checkbox}
{allergy_checkbox:value}
{/allergy_checkbox}

{/exp:smart_members:profile}
```